# Dynamic Shipping Rates With PayPal Smart Buttons

Tags: javascript, paypal, shopify, paypal-rest-sdk

I use PayPal smart buttons on my website. How can I make different shipping rates by country? I tried this one here according to PayPal tutorial:

```
    <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
  paypal.Buttons({
     
          style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',
          
        },

            createOrder: function(data, actions) {

                return actions.order.create({

                    purchase_units: [{
                      description:  document.getElementById("Color").innerText,
                        amount: {
                         
                          value:
                          {{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}
                          },

                    }]
                        
                });
            },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '! Thank You For Your 
            Purchase');
          });
        },
```

const baseOrderAmount = '15.00';
onShippingChange: function(data, actions) {

```
        // Patch the shipping amount
        const shippingAmount = data.shipping_address.country_code === 'US' ? '5.00' : '0.00';
        return actions.order.patch([
            {
                op: 'replace',
                path: '/purchase_units/@reference_id==\'default\'/amount',
                value: {
                    currency_code: 'USD',
                    value: (parseFloat(baseOrderAmount) + parseFloat(shippingAmount)).toFixed(2),
                    breakdown: {
                        item_total: {
                            currency_code: 'USD',
                            value: baseOrderAmount
                        },
                        shipping: {
                            currency_code: 'USD',
                            value: shippingAmount
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I am trying to make 5$ shipping only to the USA since this is my supplier fees..I tried also some if/else statements but nothing seems to work ! What am I doing wrong? Or maybe anyone knows other way to make this with these PayPal Buttons? Didn't fing anything helpful so far. BTW - Using Shopify Narrative Theme for what it worth.

Comment: If you're using a Shopify cart, how is this code actually being called? Also you have multiple "paypal.Buttons" here, what looks like some syntax errors after the first one, and the second one has only an 'onShippingChange' with no other code. There's no way that can work.

Comment: Yeah just noticed about this. Simple copy-paste mistake. Just corrected it now. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Syntax seems more okay now, but again I have no idea how Shopify is actually calling this code. Shopify has its own built-in implementation of a PayPal checkout as I understand it. As far as I know this code of yours is additional (you wrote/added it?), not being called, and hence being ignored.